# Android app and placement

Tags: android, admob, ads, facebook-audience-network

I have an Android app, appnhas only one screen and it has a buttons layout at the top and buttons layout at the bottom. Center area is to draw. 
Where should I place an banner ad on this app and what should be the padding margin etc to avaoid any admob or Facebook ads policies?

Comment: Hi @kau_m please can you put your app screenshot here of that particular screen in which you should have to put the banner ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to review and follow the ad-placement guidelines for whichever ad platform you intend to use.

Comment: Even after reviewing their guidelines it&#39;s not clear that what is the acceptable margin betweens ad placement and buttons to avoid accidental clicks. 7 dp of space between ad and app button still gets the ad account disabled. Leaving too much margin on a single page app leaves less space for actual app functionality.

Comment: If the specific guidelines are not clear, either post the guidelines you're not clear about so people to give you feedback, or reach out to the respective platform's support help for clarification.